# How do you access data for List Builderin Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui

I'm very new to flutter and I'm having a scoping problem with the list builder. I have a I've declared a list and cannot access it within my Widget.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
List myList=["1", "2","8","4"];
  Widget optionsWrapper = Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
          child: Column(children: [ListView.builder(
            itemCount: myList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return ListTile(title: Text(myList))
      }
          )
      ])
      ),
])

//optionsWrapper is included in the rest of the app, down here in a Widget build function..
}
```

Comment: Hi! Just move all optionsWrapper code to build function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely want to keep your code separate from the `build` method for cleanliness (suggested, actually), you can't just have your `optionsWrapper` as an instance variable.

That's because initializers can't have access to instance variables.

So, it is suggested to have a function in your class that builds the list.

Also, you have two issues in your code.

1. You don't need a `Column` to wrap your `ListView.builder` since `ListView.builder` already lays out it's children vertically.
2. You were accessing your `myList` in a wrong way. You need to pass `index` as well like this `Text(myList[index])`.

Finally,

```
Widget buildOptionsWrapper() => Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: myList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(title: Text(myList[index]));
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Wherver you want to use this function, just call `buildOptionsWrapper()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring widget as a variable, you can create a `function` like this

```
List myList = ['1', '2', '8', '4'];
  Widget optionsWrapper() {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
                itemCount: myList.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      myList[index],
                    ),
                  );
                })
          ],
        ))
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In flutter everything is **Widget**

You can create a widget for OptionWrapper and use where ever you want.

```
class OptionWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> myList;

  const OptionWrapper({Key key, this.myList}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: [
      Expanded(
          child: Column(children: [
        ListView.builder(
            itemCount: myList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(title: Text(myList[index]));
            })
      ])),
    ]);
  }
}
```